# Clear autocomplete value on select change event

Tags: kendo-ui

I have the following http://jsfiddle.net/TgBzB/3/ and want to clear the autocomplete field when the user has selected an item. The following code does not do this:-

```js
$("#input").data("kendoAutoComplete").value("");
```

Is this possible?

```js
//create AutoComplete UI component
$("#input").kendoAutoComplete({
    dataSource: data,
    filter: "startswith",
    placeholder: "Select country...",
    select: function(e) {
        var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
        $('#list').append("<li>" + dataItem + "</li>");
        //How do I clear the #input here?
        $("#input").data("kendoAutoComplete").value(""); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code clears the input, but the select event fires to early and the value is added after. What you have to do is to clear the input at `change` event :

```js
$("#input").kendoAutoComplete({
    dataSource: data,
    filter: "startswith",
    placeholder: "Select country...",
    select: function(e) {
        var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
        $('#list').append("<li>" + dataItem + "</li>");
    },
    change: function(e) {
        $("#input").data("kendoAutoComplete").value(""); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Ta, should have thought about this a bit more:

Comment: Have also found a nicer cleaner way, but will still keep this as accepted answer...

Comment: @Rippo yes nice solution indeed since moreover it doesn't loose the previous value if the field loose the focus without having selected a value (which triggers a change event but not a select one)...

Comment: By the way, you don't need to search the DOM for the element to retrieve a reference to the widget in your event handler. A reference is passed in the first argument of the event handler: `e.sender`. So the code would be: `e.sender.clear("")`.  Not only is this easier, it's faster too!

Comment: Correcion on @KevinBabcock's comment: `e.sender.value("");` will work.

Answer (score 4):

This is also another alternative which works just as well, instead of clearing it after a change event simply stop it from showing in first place by using `e.preventDefault();`

```
...
select: function(e) {
        var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
        $('#list').append("<li>" + dataItem + "</li>");
        $("#input").data("kendoAutoComplete").value("");
        e.preventDefault();
}
...
```

Have updated the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rippo/TgBzB/8/

Answer (score 0):

```
select: function(e) {
```

....
  e.preventDefault();

}

wont allow you to search same key word (type immediately). it will work if you type same key word character by character with giving some milliseconds time.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine even if you use MVVM binding to multiselect value.

```
select: function(e) {
    var widget = $('#widgetId').data('kendoMultiSelect');
    widget.input.val('');
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Simply Using this you can clear the auto complete

```
       $("#autoCompleteName").val("");
```